# What is the blocks column in edquota output?

Tags: linux, quota

I know what are hard and soft limits, but what means "blocks" column in edquota utility? I not found this at Internet and mans...

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood. It is how much blocks there are currently used by the current user.